# How do I process date and time on SQL and PHP?

Tags: php, sql, datetime

```
Table - user_feed  
column name - date_n_time (type - datetime)
```

How do I write the PHP code to check if the `date_n_time` of a particular row in the table - `user_feed` is within 5 days from now (for example)?
What's a permanent fix for processing date and time in PHP and SQL?

Comment: From all answers, I advise you to take one of the MySQL Query solution. MySQL's engine got commands for date and time, so use it and save PHP time for something else.

Comment: Should i always do that everytime i've to decide between MySQL and PHP? Will that make server side faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [date](http://id2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) object in PHP. With its timestamp, you can customize it however you like.  It's pretty simple.

From the manual:

```
// Prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be written in SQL directly and would look something like this (for example):
`SELECT INTERVAL 5 DAY + column;`

The permanent fix would be reading the documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

If the value is a linux time-stamp you can compare it to time():

```
if( date_n_time <= ( time() - 5*24*60*60 ) ){    //days hours mins secs
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This SQL code would work for PHP as well so to check your condition:

```
select * from user_feed where date_n_time  > GETDATE () -5
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're about to compare it in the scripting side:

```
abs(strtotime(date_n_time) / (24*3600)) < 5
```

Please note that this line is **both past- and future-proof**, because you referred to it as '5 days from now'.

For database side solution, you'll need to check your vendor's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");// current date

$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +2 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +30 days");
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to handle dates and times in PHP with MySQL, is to use the datetime datatype in MySQL then use the MySQL date functions. You can use the date functions to convert the date to a unix timestamp and then modify it in PHP if you like.